# Quickblox giving SmackException$NotConnectedException in android app

Tags: java, android, chat, quickblox

We have integrated quickblox sdk in our android app for chatting.. We have implemented chat, friend request functionality in the app. But, we are getting this exception when one user accepts friend request of another user. We also tried to google this. But, not getting any help yet. How to handle this exception or any solution to this problem. Please, help us..

This exception is coming from quickblox server while accepting friend request :

> *org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NotConnectedException* 07-14 11:35:27.120: W/System.err(11819):    at
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.sendPacket(XMPPConnection.java:584)
>   07-14 11:35:27.120: W/System.err(11819):  at
>   com.quickblox.chat.QBRoster.sendSmackPresence(QBRoster.java:347) 07-14
>   11:35:27.120: W/System.err(11819):    at
>   com.quickblox.chat.QBRoster.confirmSubscription(QBRoster.java:425)
>   07-14 11:35:27.120: W/System.err(11819):  at
>   com.ff_core.qb.helpers.QBFriendListHelper.acceptFriend(QBFriendListHelper.java:110)
>   07-14 11:35:27.120: W/System.err(11819):  at
>   com.ff_core.qb.commands.QBAcceptFriendCommand.perform(QBAcceptFriendCommand.java:34)
>   07-14 11:35:27.120: W/System.err(11819):  at
>   com.ff_core.core.command.ServiceCommand.execute(ServiceCommand.java:29)
>   07-14 11:35:27.120: W/System.err(11819):  at
>   com.ff_core.service.QBService$1.run(QBService.java:649) 07-14
>   11:35:27.120: W/System.err(11819):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>   07-14 11:35:27.120: W/System.err(11819):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>   07-14 11:35:27.120: W/System.err(11819):  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)